# Question about the existence of points and lines.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history

Say we draw a point on a graph. If the point should not take up any area than how come we could see it. Say we graph $y=x^2$, we obviously could see it. However, because $y=x^2$ is a function made up of a collection of points with no area, how come we see it? How come we see lines if they have no area?

Comment: If seeing the invisible is a problem for you, maybe math isn't the best course of study.

Comment: Not a problem just wondering.

Comment: is this like why does a water molecule not behave like water?

Comment: Why doesn't my drawing of a cat purr when I pet it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't draw a point, we draw a representation of a point.  If we drew a point, we couldn't see it. The ideal graph of $y = x^2$ would also be invisible, which wouldn't give us a whole lot of information. The representation of the graph is not the graph, because we can see it, it is inaccurate; but it does give us more information than the real graph would.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea here is that a *point* and a *line* are abstract mathematical concepts. When we "draw a point", we are just creating something concrete to represent that point. When we "draw the curve" $y = x^2$, we are creating a physical thing to represent the set of points $(x,y)$ that satisfy that function.

---

Also, since you tagged your post with (euclidean-geometry), some of Euclid's definitions are definitely relevant here. From [the list definitions in Euclid's Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/bookI.html#defs):

> - A **point** is that which has no part.
> - A **line** is breadthless length.